# Ошибка Laravel5

Tags: laravel5

При попытке отправить форму вылезает вот такая ошибка:

```
file_put_contents(D:\OSPanel\domains\vadim\storage\app/public\uploads): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Что бы это могло значить?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25186

Comment: В ошибке всё написано уже. Нет прав на запись в папку. Проверяйте права в системе.